# General Expression for capacitance of any type

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

The capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor is given by C=Aε/d.
For concentric spherical capacitor the value of capacitance is given by 4πεba/(b-a) (where b is the radius of the outer sphere and a is the radius of the inner sphere and the distance between the plates b-a).
Now a very interesting thing to note:
The geometric mean of the area of the two spheres is given by Ā=4πba.
So the expression for the capacitance of spherical capacitor becomes 
C=Āε/d (where d= b-a). Now this expression is comparable to the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor.
**So is this expression true in general?**
Capacitance=(geometric mean of the area of the surfaces x ε)/distance.

Comment: Why don't you do the calculation and see what you find?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Capacitance_of_conductors_with_simple_shapes

Comment: I am unable to do the calculation

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I voted to close because of the end *Is this result true for cylindrical capacitor also? If yes please can anyone prove it?*

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the portion that may have caused it to be closed.  (Ironically, though, the answer given by John Rennie answers the remaining question nicely by answering the removed question.)

Comment: The general expression for capacitance is:  C = Q/V. This should give a result that resembles the parallel plate formula any time the distance between the plates is small relative to the other distances in the system.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for a cylindrical capacitor. The capacitance per unit length for the cylindrical capacitor is:

$$ C = \frac{2\pi\epsilon}{\ln(b/a)} $$

The way we work out the capacitance is to put a charge $Q$ on the capacitor and calculate the electric field between the plates. Then we integrate the field to get the potential difference $V$ and the capacitance is given by $C = Q/V$.

To see how this works let's do it for the spherical capacitor:

[image: Spherical capacitor]

To calculate the field $E$ at some distance $r$ between the plates we use Gauss's law. This tells us that the total flux through the spherical surface with radius $r$ is:

$$ \Phi = \frac{Q}{\epsilon} $$

The spherical symmetry means the field $E$ is the same everywhere on the surface, so the flux is just the area of the sphere, $4\pi r^2$, times the field, $E$. So we get:

$$ 4\pi r^2 E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon} $$

or:

$$ E(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon r^2} $$

And finally the potential difference is just the integral of $E(r)$ from $r = a$ to $r = b$:

$$ V = \int_a^b E(r) = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon} \left(\frac1a - \frac1b \right) $$

So:

$$ C = \frac{Q}{V} = 4\pi\epsilon\frac{ab}{b-a} $$

It doesn't involve taking the geometric mean at all. Whether there is any fundamental significance to the geometric mean appearing in the equation I don't know, but I don't think so.

Just for completeness let's do the cylindrical capacitor. Refer to the diagram above again, but this time take it to be the cross section through the concentric cylinders. This time the area of the cylindrical Gaussian surface is $2\pi r \ell$, so we get the field as:

$$ E(r) = \frac{Q}{2 \pi\epsilon r \ell} $$

And when we integrate this the $1/r$ integrates to $\ln(r)$ so we get:

$$ V = \frac{Q}{2 \pi\epsilon \ell} \ln(b/a) $$

And:

$$ C = \frac{Q}{V} = \frac{2\pi \epsilon \ell}{\ln(b/a)} $$

Divide by $\ell$ to get the capacitance per unit length and you get the equation at the top of my answer.